# counting prime number issue with Miller Rabin test in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to count prime numbers by Miller Rabin test with the upper band and lower band,  like between 1000 up 1000000 how many primes will be generating I missed it the count function, anybody here to help me o this issue please and your comments and advice will be appreciated and pasted the Miller Rabin code in the below 
waiting for your kind feedback

```
# Python3 program Miller-Rabin primality test 
import time 
import random 
lower=int(input("Enter the lower limit for the range:"))
upper=int(input("Enter the upper numbers for limit the range:"))
# Utility function to do 
# modular exponentiation. 
# It returns (x^y) % p 
def power(x, y, p): 

    # Initialize result 
    res = 1; 

    # Update x if it is more than or 
    # equal to p 
    x = x % p; 
    while (y > 0): 

        # If y is odd, multiply 
        # x with result 
        if (y & 1): 
            res = (res * x) % p; 

        # y must be even now 
        y = y>>1; # y = y/2 
        x = (x * x) % p; 

    return res; 

# This function is called 
# for all k trials. It returns 
# false if n is composite and 
# returns false if n is 
# probably prime. d is an odd 
# number such that d*2<sup>r</sup> = n-1 
# for some r >= 1 
start_time = time.time()
def miillerTest(d, n): 

    # Pick a random number in [2..n-2] 
    # Corner cases make sure that n > 4 
    a = 2 + random.randint(1, n - 4); 

    # Compute a^d % n 
    x = power(a, d, n); 

    if (x == 1 or x == n - 1): 
        return True; 

    # Keep squaring x while one 
    # of the following doesn't 
    # happen 
    # (i) d does not reach n-1 
    # (ii) (x^2) % n is not 1 
    # (iii) (x^2) % n is not n-1 
    while (d != n - 1): 
        x = (x * x) % n; 
        d *= 2; 

        if (x == 1): 
            return False; 
        if (x == n - 1): 
            return True; 

    # Return composite 
    return False; 

# It returns false if n is 
# composite and returns true if n 
# is probably prime. k is an 
# input parameter that determines 
# accuracy level. Higher value of 
# k indicates more accuracy. 
def isPrime( n, k): 
    # Corner cases 
    if (n <= 1 or n == 4): 
        return False; 
    if (n <= 3): 
        return True; 

    # Find r such that n = 
    # 2^d * r + 1 for some r >= 1 
    d = n - 1; 
    while (d % 2 == 0): 
        d //= 2; 

    # Iterate given nber of 'k' times 
    for i in range(k): 
        if (miillerTest(d, n) == False): 

            return False; 

    return True; 

# Driver Code 
# Number of iterations 
k = 4; 

print("All primes smaller than 200: "); 
for n in range(100 ,1000): 
    if (isPrime(n, k)):  
        print(n , end=" "); 
def count(n_lower,n_upper):
        count1=0
        for j in range(n_lower,n_upper):
            for i in range(1,j):
                if j%i==0:
                   factor=i
            if factor>1:
                count1+=1
        return count1

print(count(lower,upper))
end_time = time.time()
print("Following are the composite numbers smaller b/w 10^5 to 10^6")
print("Total time:%0.5f" % (end_time - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a test that creates an algorithmic k test so that random numbers and increasing iterations aren't needed, you can use this:

```
def ltrailing(N):
    return len(str(bin(N))) - len(str(bin(N)).rstrip('0'))

def MillerRabin(N, primetest, iterx, powx, withstats=False): 
  primetest = pow(primetest, powx, N) 
  if withstats == True:
     print("first: ",primetest) 
  if primetest == 1 or primetest == N - 1: 
    return True 
  else: 
    for x in range(0, iterx-1): 
       primetest = pow(primetest, 2, N) 
       if withstats == True:
          print("else: ", primetest) 
       if primetest == N - 1: return True 
       if primetest == 1: return False 
  return False 

def sfactorint_isprime(N, withstats=False):
    if N == 2:
      return True
    if N % 2 == 0:
      return False
    if N < 2:
        return False
    iterx = ltrailing(N - 1)
    """ This k test is an algorithmic test builder instead of using
        random numbers. The offset of k, from -2 to +2 produces pow tests
        that fail or pass instead of having to use random numbers and more
        iterations. All you need are those 5 numbers from k to get a 
        primality answer. 
    """
    k = pow(N, (1<<N.bit_length())-1, 1<<N.bit_length()) - 1
    t = N >> iterx
    tests = [k-2, k-1, k, k+1, k+2]
    for primetest in tests:
        if primetest >= N:
            primetest %= N
        if primetest >= 2:
            if MillerRabin(N, primetest, iterx, t, withstats) == False:
                return False
    return True
```